# How to obtain by parameter the cron on Camunda modeler?

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I have a process modeled with Camunda modeler, when i put a Timer Definition with a property like {cronProperty} i get the following error when i try to deploy on Cockpit:

```
Deployment failed :
ENGINE-09026 Exception while parsing cron expression '{cronProperty}': Unexpected character: {
```

[image]

There is a way to put "0 0 * * * ?" as a property instead of hardcode? I need to define the cron in base of the environment

Answer (score 0):

I think you just missed the `$`,

Like `${cronProperty}`